# For what $a$ is this integral convergent?$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\cos(x))*(\tan(x))^a dx$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I’m new here and I’m trying to solve this exercise:

For what $a$ does the integral converge?

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\cos(x))*(\tan(x))^a dx$$
$$a \in \mathbb{R}$$

So far I got to

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(t)}{t^a} dt$$

(by Limit Comparison Test with

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(\cos(x))*\frac{\sin(x)}{(\cos(x))^a} dx$$ and subbing $t= \cos(x)$)  but I don't know how to solve this. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) with more care. For instance, there is no `\real` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a\geq 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}-\dfrac{\log t}{t^{a}}dt&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(1/t)}{t^{a}}dt\\
&\geq\int_{0}^{1/3}\dfrac{\log(1/t)}{t^{a}}dt\\
&\geq\int_{0}^{1/3}\dfrac{1}{t^{a}}\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, why do we need to work with $$\int_{0}^{1/3}dt$$ instead? Also, is there a way to prove convergence for a<1?

Comment: Because I want to get the constant bound $\dfrac{\log(1/t)}{t^{a}}\geq\dfrac{1}{t^{a}}$ for all $t\in(0,1/3)$, remember that $e<3$ and $\log e=1$. If not, you can get a bound $C>0$ which is valid for all $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: For $a<1$, you know that $\log(1/t)\leq C_{a}(1/t)^{(1-a)/3}$ and we note that $(1-a)/3+a<1$.

Comment: I understand the divergence now, but I don’t get the approximation of log(1/t), is that a special formula or sth? I’m in MA2 class and we haven’t covered that. Could you please provide further explanation?

Comment: I see. A cheating way is to use L'Hopital rule to compute $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log(1/t)}{(1/t)^{\beta}}=0$ for any $\beta>0$, so there is a constant $C_{\beta}>0$ such that for small $t>0$, $\log(1/t)\leq C_{\beta}(1/t)^{\beta}$.

Comment: So now, if I understood everything correctly, the resulting integral is $$\int_{0}^{1/3} 1/t^a dt$$ + $$\int_{1/3}^{1} logt/t^a dt$$ where the first integral converges for a<1 and the second is also convergent (by being continuous)

Comment: Yes, you are right.